# How to create for each of the MS Access datatables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, foreach, datatable

How to create for each of the MS Access datatables in vb.net?.
So I want to appear one by one according to "EMPID" in print preview.
should appear in those print preview based on one row each

```
  Private Sub Generate()
        report.Clear()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim query = "Select EMPID,[NAME],MONTHLYSALARY From tblemployee"
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, Con)
            adapter.Fill(dt)
        End Using
 For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim EMPID As String = row("EMPID").ToString()
            Dim NAME As String = row("NAME").ToString()
            Dim MONTHLYSALARY As String = row("MONTHLYSALARY").ToString()
        report.AddDataTable(dt)
            report.NewPage()
        Next row
    End Sub
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Generate()
        report.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
    End Sub
```

[image: Print preview]
[image: Print preview in 3 page]

'desired Result
[image: Desired Result Page One]
[image: Desired Result Page Two]
[image: Desired Result Page Three]

[image: option report]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Please try to provide a more detailed explanation. I suspect that you're not a native English speaker and, in that case, the temptation can be to provide less explanation but it generally requires more explanation to get the point across clearly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , I have updated the description and also screenshots.According to your recommendations

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to print one record per page?

Comment: Are you asking to make each EMPID print on a separate page maybe?  Maybe you could add a picture of your expected output?

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Yes, that's right, I want to print one row on one page

Comment: @Hursey , `Are you asking to make each EMPID print on a separate page maybe?` yes right I want to print one ROW in one page according to empID. `Maybe you could add a picture of your expected output?` Okay I give you an example screenshot

Comment: This really has nothing to do with the `DataTable`. This is something that would be configured in the report, but you haven't actually told us what `report` is in your code. If the way its done is to add a `DataTable` and then a page break then you actually need three `DataTables`, but you're adding the same `DataTable` three times.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , I'm using kimtooreport, I think this only does for each of the datatable so in that code I've created the code "report. NewPage()" so it will create a perpage. So this is no problem with the report I use

Comment: There is not a problem with the report you use. There is a problem with how you use it. You have one `DataTable` that contains three rows. You add that whole `DataTable`, then a new page, then the whole `DataTable` again, then a new page, then the whole `DataTable` again. Does that make sense? No, it doesn't. If you wanted to do it that way, you'd need three `DataTables` that contained one row each. In your loop, you need to create a new `DataTable` from the current row and then add that, not the original `DataTable` containing all the rows.

Comment: Having said that, I think the first thing to do would be to look for an alternative to the `AddDataTable` method you're calling. If there's an `AddDataRow` method then you should call that to add just the current row. If there's only an `AddDataRows` method then you could probably put the current row in an array and add that. That should be your first option, then create three new `DataTables` if that first option is not available.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , There is no choice as you said and there is only the option that I just uploaded a screenshot of in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in the comments, this loop doesn't make sense as it is:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim EMPID As String = row("EMPID").ToString()
    Dim NAME As String = row("NAME").ToString()
    Dim MONTHLYSALARY As String = row("MONTHLYSALARY").ToString()
    report.AddDataTable(dt)
    report.NewPage()
Next row
```

As it is, you loop through rows and get the field values from the current row and just ignore them, then add the whole table to the report. You add the whole table to the report multiple times, once for each row.

I don't use that reporting tool and there doesn't seem to be any proper documentation at present so I'll make an educated guess at what to do. Your first choice should be to use a method that allows you to add a single `DataRow`, if one exists, e.g.

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    report.AddDataRow(row)
    report.NewPage()
Next row
```

If that's not possible, the next option should be a method that allows you to add a list of `DataRows`, e.g.

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    report.AddDataRows({row})
    report.NewPage()
Next row
```

If that's not possible, you can stick with the method you're using to add a `DataTable` but you need to create a new `DataTable` for each row, not add the existing `DataTable`, containing all the rows, multiple times, e.g.

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim table = {row}.CopyToDataTable()

    report.AddDataTable(table)
    report.NewPage()
Next row
```

EDIT:

Based on the screenshot that was added to the question of methods available, you might also use `DataViews` of the original `DataTable` instead of new `DataTables`, e.g.

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim view = New DataView(dt, row(dt.PrimaryKey.First()), Nothing, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)

    report.AddDataView(view)
    report.NewPage()
Next row
```

That assumes that the `DataTable` has a `PrimaryKey` and it is a single column. Presumably your `EMPID` should be the PK. If it's not, try setting the `MissingSchemaAction` property of your data adapter to `AddWithKey` and the PK information should be propagated from the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only one that goes perfectly is `report.AddDataTable(table)` . I tried your code but he made the page 4 even though the fourth page is a blank page. if I use dataview then there is an error `Sequence contains no elements`

Comment: @user18, if there are four pages then that is presumably because your are calling `NewPage` three times. There would be one page by default and then every `NewPage` call would add a new page, so three calls 1+3=4 pages. You should call `NewPage` one less time than there are rows in the table. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: As for the code not working using `DataViews`, that would be because your table has no primary key. I specifically stated in the answer that that code relied on there being a primary key consisting of one column. Maybe read all the information that people have gone to the trouble to provide instead of just copying and pasting code blindly.

Comment: `As for the code not working using DataViews, that would be because your table has no primary key. I specifically stated in the answer that that code relied on there being a primary key consisting of one column. Maybe read all the information that people have gone to the trouble to provide instead of just copying and pasting code blindly.` . in tblemployee I have a primary key, namely the column "EMPID" with data type text

Comment: Read the words! I'm talking about the `DataTable`, not the database table. I've already told you what to do. I shouldn't have to repeat myself when the words are there to be read as many times as you need to understand.

Comment: Thank you the answer from you went very perfectly